# Deal with missing frames when creating video with ffmpeg

Tags: bash, file, ffmpeg, runtime-error

I am trying to assemble a video from a several thousands images that have been post processed by a vision script. The process is not perfect and I will have a few frames fail (like 20 out of 10K). My issue is I use a command like

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -start_number 11 -i image-%d.jpeg -vf "crop=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" movie.mp4
```

So this will fail as soon as it stumbles upon a failed image because it will be missing in the folder for example

```
Could not open file : image-727.jpegtrate=4305.2kbits/s speed=1.54x     
image-%d.jpeg: Input/output error
```

How can I get around this? I would like to avoid having to renumber so many files. I could have as many as 100K for a given run.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the glob pattern type for the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpeg' -vf "crop=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" movie.mp4
```

Because your file names do no appear to have any zero padding you will probably need to add `sort`:

```
cat $(find . -name '*.jpeg' -print | sort -V) | ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i - -vf "crop=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" movie.mp4
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I tried out the command and I get this cryptic error `pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input` I am not sure what would be invalid.

Comment: also I tried just running the sort and I get a lot of binary garbage instead of a list of files in order am I missing something?

Comment: @TheCodeNovice There was a typo in the first command. I updated the answer. The version with `sort` is expected to give you binary data, not a list. The binary data is being piped to ffmpeg. If you want a simple list to verify file order just run `find . -name '*.jpeg' -print | sort -V`

Comment: - thanks for looking at this ... the sort works byitself but the ffmpeg still does not like the data being piped. If I put `-f image2` which is supposed to tell ffmpeg that I am piping jpegs i get a different error ` Could find no file with path 'pipe:' and index in the range 0-4 pipe:: No such file or directory`. The command I am using is `cat $(find . -name '*.jpeg' -print | sort -V) | ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 30 -i - -vf "crop=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" movie.mp4`. The only thing in the directory are the images

Comment: @TheCodeNovice Copy and paste all of the text from the console output. Use a pastebin site and provide the link in a comment.

Comment: here is the full output for both attempts https://pastebin.com/uJQGpi7w

Comment: @TheCodeNovice Don't use `-f image2`. Try adding `-maxdepth 1` to `find`. If that doesn't work I recommend renaming sequentially. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77104 for a few methods including using symbolic links.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am close. I was able to get a movie with `cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -i pipe:.jpg -vf "crop=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" movie.mp4`. My only remaining problem is I get the the periodic flicker of a frame not in the right order probably due to a lack of sort. Any reason why the bare cat command works but your more elaborate one would not. If I try and use your cat statement with a sort it just sits there with no error.

Comment: I tried merging your sort with my ffmpeg that sort of worked and I get the following https://pastebin.com/em2Vky3f